# Kibana filtering by Unique count

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

[image: Kibana Filtering by Unique count]

Hello,
I am wondering if it is possible to filter on this dashboard by unique count.

I would like to see the entries in the left column where unique count is 4 or less. Is this possible?

Thanks.